# TYPO3 : get lastest data to XML

Tags: typo3

I have an xml generated to get my news but the xml file is filled with more and more news, I want a way to get only the 10 latest news for example

I tried to add the "limit" option to my configuration of XML but it limit the news starting with the oldest so I can't get the more recent news, maybe I'm using this option wrong, or I have to combine it with an option like orderby but I don't know the available options that can be used for xml, it's my first time

something have an Idea to how can I solve my issue ? thanks

there is my setup.ts :

```
           settings {
                        categories = {$xml.rss.channel.categories}
                        limit = {$xml.rss.channel.limit}
                        detailPid = {$xml.rss.channel.detailPid}
                        startingpoint = {$xml.rss.channel.startingpoint}
                        format = xml
                    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the manual you can find the setting [`orderDirection`](https://docs.typo3.org/p/georgringer/news/10.0/en-us/Reference/TypoScript/PluginSettings.html#sort-direction-orderdirection)

so your configuration should include:

```
plugin.tx_news.settings.orderDirection = desc
```